# Preventing +-, in an input type=number

Tags: html

I was just wondering if there was a (non-js) solution to prevent `"+"`, `"-"`, `","` , `"."` to be typed in an `<input type="number">` in HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the solution of other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
</input>
```

I think the only solution is to control what key is pressed and only accent keys from 0 to 9, using their ASCII char code.

I have been researching a way to do only in HTML, but I haven't found anything that works in all browsers.

I don't know if this solution allow the using of backspace, but it would be as easy as include it in the `onkeypress` event

Comment: Cheers sir, that's exactly what I needed. The solution was quite obvious, how dumb was I ...

Comment: If you like the solution, you can accept it, but I didn't find a solution that no uses Javascript

Comment: I mean, I didn't want to have js to target elements and apply rules on it, I don't mind having some js directly on my elements that way, I should have been more specific in my question.

Comment: So, you should accept the answer clicking on the green tick

Comment: Indeed, it was just to early to do so before